# Why do I keep receiving a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: string, loops, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to write a program that takes a string and removes all instances of another string from it. For example: `("Remove them all!", "em")` would print `"Rove th all!"`. However, when I do run this, it give me `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public class LabFive {

    public static String removeAll(String oldPhrase, String removal){
        String newPhrase = "";
        for(int i = 0; i <= oldPhrase.length(); i++){
            if(oldPhrase.substring(i, (removal.length() + i)) == removal)
                newPhrase = newPhrase + oldPhrase.substring((removal.length() + 2 + i), oldPhrase.length());        
        }
        return(newPhrase);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(removeAll("AaAaAa", "a"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `replace("em", "")`?

Comment: Why don't you look at the answer given, and perhaps [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that helps you most?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have several issues. Firstly, you can't use `==` to check for string equality, you have to use `String.equals()` method. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Secondly, your `for` loop iterates from `0` to `oldPhrase.length()` inclusive, but trying to use this length value for index will cause the exception to occur. In java, strings have zero-based index, so index starts from 0 and ends at `oldPhrase.length()-1`.

Third, your logic seems broken. The `substring(int, int)` method's parameters are `beginIndex` and `endIndex`. So:

```
newPhrase = newPhrase + oldPhrase.substring((removal.length() + 2 + i), oldPhrase.length());
```

concatenating part of the `oldPhrase` *till the end* to the `newPhrase` is **not** going to do what you want.

---

Here is the way I did it. The idea is simpler, and also clearer. I have added comment to make it clear.

Test the code live on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Dwsx/1)

```
public static String removeAll(String oldPhrase, String removal) {

    // if removal is not found return the original string
    if(oldPhrase.indexOf(removal) == -1) {
        return oldPhrase;
    }

    int removalLength = removal.length(); // storing the length so as not to call .length() again and again

    for(int i = 0; i < oldPhrase.length(); i++) { // note that <= will cause the exception too
        int idxOfRemoval = oldPhrase.indexOf(removal);

        if(idxOfRemoval == i) { // removal is found at the current index, i.e. at index i
            // take substring from beginning to index of removal +
            // substring from the end of removal to end of original string
            oldPhrase = oldPhrase.substring(0, idxOfRemoval) + oldPhrase.substring(idxOfRemoval+removalLength);
        }
    }
    return(oldPhrase);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeAll("AaAaAa", "a"));
}
```

Output:

```
AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to explain the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is in your loop:

```java
for(int i = 0; i <= oldPhrase.length(); i++){...}
```

since `i` is going to be equal to `oldPhrase.length()` you have a problem with getting the substring:

```java
oldPhrase.substring(i, (removal.length() + i))
```

so you end up with eventually

```java
oldPhrase.substring(oldPhrase.length(), (removal.length() + oldPhrase.length()))
```

This is a problem because the highest index in a string is `length - 1` and you're trying to access the index at `length`.

A brute force way of doing `removeAll` would be to iterate over your string (as you did) and just check, for each character at `i`, if `removal` starts there and then the string you want to return would be

`sub(0,i) + removeAll(the rest off your string starting at i+removal.length)`

```java
public static String removeAll(String oldPhrase,String removal) {
    int rem = removal.length();
    int n = oldPhrase.length();
    // if length of oldPhrase is shorter than removal
    // then there nothing you need to remove
    if (n < rem) return oldPhrase;

    // iterate over your string
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - rem; i++) {
        int j;
        // check if there is a substring, removal, starting at i
        for (j = 0; j < rem; j++) {
            if (oldPhrase.charAt(i+j) != removal.charAt(j))
                break;
        }
        // if there is...
        if (j == rem) {
            // return stuff before substring you want to remove +
            //        removeAll(the stuff after substring you want to remove)
            return  oldPhrase.substring(0,i) + removeAll(oldPhrase.substring(i+rem,n),removal);
        }
    }
    return oldPhrase;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeAll("AaAaAa", "a"));
}
```

output:

`AAA`